# How to insert a value inside an XML tag in XML file using a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, xml

I have the following XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Topology>
 <MyProjectserver1 desc="name of the server"></MyProjectserver1>
 </Topology>
```

I have tried the following, but it did not get update

```
$path = 'C:\newfolder\data.xml'
$MyProjectserver1 ='XYZAB'
$xml =[xml](Get-Content -Path $path)
$node =$xml.Topology.MyProjectserver1 |
Where {$_.desc -eq 'name of the server'}
$node =$MyProjectserver1
$xml.Save($path)
```

Once the above PowerShell script is executed, it did not update the XML content.

Ideally, the PowerShell script should update the server name in XML content as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Topology>
 <MyProjectserver1 desc="name of the server">XYZAB</MyProjectserver1>
 </Topology>
```

Comment: Why are you using PowerShell instead of simply editing the file with a text editor?

Comment: Simply editing the file can be done and it is a manual activity. I'm looking to automate this manual activity using powershell, so that script can be scheduled and gets the xml updated

Comment: The XML above seems to be incorrect but that may be a superuser.com problem. The line that contains "MyProjectserver1" is malformed XML

Comment: In the powershell code, Toplogy should be Topology methinks

Comment: Thankyou , the Toplogy in the powershell code is a typo.
Actually I have used Topology only. Please let me know if any workaround works for this scenario

Comment: Is the fact that, in both snippets of XML above, the MyProjectserver1 node has no closing > also a typo?

Comment: Yes, have edited the node now. As I have manually written it, there has a more chance of typos

Comment: Keep in mind you should include minimal reproductible code examples. Your code still has mistakes, even in the 1st line. Please make sure it runs it before submitting next edit.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example, you need to set `InnerText` property of the XML node:

```
$node.InnerText = $MyProjectserver1
```

See `XmlNode.InnerText` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext?view=net-8.0)

Comment: This I have already tried using InnerText and it doesnt update

Comment: How so? Show your entire code after applying the change. It's impossible for it to not work, unless e.g. your `'name of the server'` string is incorrect.

Comment: It does not work with the code I have posted. Have you tried before answering here and is it worked ?
I believe it does not work

Comment: Yes, it worked fine and still works fine. Except your code in question has still an obvious breaking quoting bug, because 2 people have not accepted my edit correcting it and you have not corrected it yourself as requested.